# Keeping alias types simple in Python documentation?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, type-hinting, type-alias

I'm trying to use the `typing` module to document my Python package, and I have a number of situations where several different types are allowable for a function parameter. For instance, you can either pass a number, an Envelope object (one of the classes in my package), or a list of numbers from which an Envelope is constructed, or a list of lists of numbers from which an envelope is constructed. So I make an alias type as follows:

```
NumberOrEnvelope = Union[Sequence[Real], Sequence[Sequence[Real]], Real, Envelope]
```

Then I write the function:

```
def example_function(parameter: NumberOrEnvelope):
    ...
```

And that looks great to me. However, when I create the documentation using Sphinx, I end up with this horrifically unreadable function signature:

*example_function(parameter: Union[Sequence[numbers.Real], Sequence[Sequence[numbers.Real]], numbers.Real, expenvelope.envelope.Envelope])*

Same thing also with the hints that pop up when I start to try to use the function in PyCharm.

Is there some way I can have it just leave it as "NumberOrEnvelope". Ideally that would also link in the documentation to a clarification of what "NumberOrEnvelope" is, though even if it didn't it would be way better than what's appearing now.

Comment: `example_function` should almost certainly be two or more separate functions. At the very least, `example_function_2(parameter: Sequence[Real])` can be implemented in terms of `example_function_1(parameter: Real)`.

Comment: I understand why you would say that, but to give a little more detail: it's a music library, and one of the functions in question is the play_note method of the instrument class. It takes three arguments (pitch, volume, length), and the both pitch and volume would be this NumberOrEnvelope type. If I made it separate functions for each possible combination of the pitch and the volume argument, I'd end up with like 9 copies of the same function. I prefer the simplicity of a single function with flexible argument types.

Comment: The function design seems fine to me. It's like how most NumPy functions take arraylikes. Imagine trying to split every NumPy function based on whether each argument is an array, a scalar, a nested sequence, an object with an `__array__` method, an object with a `__numpy_ufunc__` method, etc.

Comment: That's a really good example of what I'm trying to do. And it looks like numpy's solution is simply to not type-hint for that argument and just call it "array_like".

Comment: Why are there so many ways to specify a pitch (or a volume, or a length)?

Comment: The library treats musical parameters very flexibly. Pitch can either be a number representing the MIDI pitch, or an Envelope, which represents a pitch that changes dynamically over time. That dynamically changing value is represented by an `Envelope` object, but since writing `Envelope.from_levels([69, 60, 67])` is cumbersome, I allow, as a shorthand, for people to pass the list [69, 60, 67] with the understanding that it will be interpreted as an Envelope. Similarly [[69, 60, 67], [1, 0.5, 2]] is a shorthand for `Envelope.from_levels_and_durations([69, 60, 67], [1, 0.5, 2])`

Comment: Would [autodoc_type_aliases](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_type_aliases) be helpful?

Comment: @xuhdev yes, I think so — thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and used https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_type_aliases, introduced in version 3.3.

In your sphinx conf.py, insert this section. It does not seem to make much sense at the first sight, but does the trick:

```
autodoc_type_aliases = dict(NumberOrEnvelope='NumberOrEnvelope')
```

Warning: It only works in modules that start with `from __future__ import annotation`

Note: If there is a target in the documentation, type references even have a hyperlink to the definition. I have classes, documented elsewhere with autoclass, which are used as types of function parameters, and the docs show the nice names of the types with links.

Answer (score 0):

Support for this appears to be in the works.

- See [`Issue #6518`](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/6518).
- That issue can be closed by the recent updates to [`Pull Request #8007`](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/8007) (under review).

If you want the fix ASAP, you can perhaps try using that build.

Comment: I still experience this issue in 2022 (version 5.1.1). Could it be that this is not in the release?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I also had this issue and was very confused why the accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73273330/1822018 was not working for me. I solved my problem and I am posting it here for the benefit of others.

Comment: In my case, I also had installed the Python package sphinx-autodocs-typehints which extends/hijacks/overrides certain Sphinx functionality, in particular it appears to supplant the functionality of the autodoc_type_aliases dictionary in the given PR. To anyone trying to debug this issue I would suggest removing 'sphinx_autodoc_typehints' from the extensions list in your Sphinx conf.py file.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: This doesn't quite work, sadly.

Turns out after a little more searching, I found what I was looking for. Instead of:

```
NumberOrEnvelope = Union[Sequence[Real], Sequence[Sequence[Real]], Real, Envelope]
```

I found that you can create your own compound type that does the same thing:

```
NumberOrEnvelope = TypeVar("NumberOrEnvelope", Sequence[Real], Sequence[Sequence[Real]], Real, Envelope)
```

This displays in documentation as "NumberOrEnvelope", just as I wanted.

Comment: This doesn't actually do the same thing as the alias. For example, with the TypeVar, a function like `def foo(a: NumberOrEnvelope, b: NumberOrEnvelope): ...` now requires the types of both parameters to match. You can't pass one `Sequence[Real]` and one `Envelope`.

Comment: Huh, that behavior strikes me as super odd. I do see, though, that the linting behaves as you say. Why on earth would it be designed that way?

Comment: TypeVars aren't intended to be another way to write unions (that's what unions are for). TypeVars are intended as a way to write generic classes and generic functions. For example, a generic class `List[T]` with an `append(self, item: T)` method requires `T` to be the same type in both cases. Similarly, a generic `blah(a: T, b: T)` function has a single `T` for the whole function.

Comment: Ah, I see that; makes perfect sense. Still, I guess I'm in a quandary; I want a Union of the type I described, but I don't want horrifically ugly and unreadable documentation. Do you have any thought about how to have a union that doesn't print out so long in the documentations?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The closest I can think of is `NewType`, but that would change how you have to call the function. Better handling may require Sphinx enhancements (unless there's some Sphinx option already in place that I'm not aware of).

Comment: I suppose if you want to "fix" this solution, you could create two typevars with different names but which allow the same types. Then they can take different actual types for a given call to the function.