# Type aliases in type hints are not preserved

Tags: python-sphinx, python-typing

My code (reduced to just a few lines for this demo) looks like this:

```py
AgentAssignment = List[int]

def assignment2str(assignment: AgentAssignment):    
    pass
```

The produced html documentation has `List[int]` as the type hint. This seems to be a resolved issue ([#6518](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/6518)), but I am still running into it in 2022 with Sphinx version 5.1.1 (and Python 3.8.2). What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

So, one needs to add at the beginning of the file (yes, before all other imports):

```py
from __future__ import annotations
```

Then in conf.py:

```py
autodoc_type_aliases = {'AgentAssignment': 'AgentAssignment'}
```

Not that this identity-transformation dictionary makes any sense to me, but it did the trick...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is Sphinx support for this yet, but you need to use explicit [PEP 613 TypeAlias introduced in Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-613-typealias). Because otherwise the type resolver cannot differentiate between a normal variable assignment and a type alias. This is a generic Python solution for the type alias problem beyond the scope of Sphinx.

```py
AgentAssignment: TypeAlias = List[int]
```

Ps. I am having the same issue with Sphinx

Comment: After upgrading to Python 10, this does not resolve the issue for me. I still get `List[int]` as the type hint in the resulting html.

Comment: Hmmmmm. Ok then I guess Sphinx does not support this yet. Thank you for trying though. I will dig through Sphinx Github later for related issues when I get to computer.

Comment: Found how it's done: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/10455. Only I don't know why they write the whole path to the alias as the value in the dictionary. For me, if I do that, the type appears that way...

Comment: [Here is another Sphinx issue tracing PEP-613](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/8934)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and was very confused why the accepted answer here [stackoverflow.com/a/73273330/1822018](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73273330/1822018), which mentions adding your type aliases to the autodoc_type_aliases dictionary as explained in the documentation here https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_type_aliases was not working for me. I solved my problem and I am posting it here for the benefit of others.

In my case, I also had installed the Python package `sphinx-autodocs-typehints` which extends/hijacks/overrides certain Sphinx functionality, in particular it appears to supplant the functionality of the autodoc_type_aliases dictionary in the given PR. To anyone trying to debug this issue I would suggest removing 'sphinx_autodoc_typehints' from the extensions list in your Sphinx conf.py file.